# In Python2.7 ANTLR4, extract tokens from a parser rule and store them in a list

Tags: python, parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

In my grammar I validate boolean expressions that look something like this:

```
((foo == true) && (bar != false) || (qux == norf))
```

I obtain the string from ANTLR4's context object by calling `getText()`:

```
def enterBody(self, ctx):
    expression = ctx.condition.getText() # condition here being shorthand for a grammar rule (`condition=expr`)
```

However, the string is returned whole (i.e. no spaces between each individual token) and I have no way of knowing what each token is:

```
((foo==true)&&(bar!=false)||(qux==norf))
```

Ideally, I would like it stored in a list in the following format:

```
['(', '(', 'foo', '==', 'true', ')', '&&', '(', 'bar', '!=', 'false', ')', '||', '(', 'qux', '==', 'norf', ')', ')']
```

The ANTLR4 Python documentation is rather sparse and I'm not sure if there's a method that accomplishes this.

Answer (score 2):

Python runtime is really similar to the Java runtime, so you can look at the [Java documentation](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/package-summary.html) and most likely the same method exists in Python. Or browse [source code](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-python2/tree/master/src/antlr4), it is pretty easy to read.

You're asking for getting a flat list of string. But the whole idea of parser is to avoid this. So I think it is most likely not the thing you need. Make sure to be aware about [parse tree and how listeners work](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parse+Tree+Listeners). Basically you should work with tree and not with flat list. What you probably are looking for is [`ParserRuleContext.getChildren()`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-python2/blob/master/src/antlr4/ParserRuleContext.py#L128). You can use it to access all child nodes:

```
def enterBody(self, ctx):
    print(list(ctx.getChildren()))
```

Which is even more likely, you want to access specific type of a child node for some action. Take a look at the parser generated by ANTLR for you. You will find bunch of `*Context` classes, which contain methods to access every type of subnode. For example `ctx` parameter of the `enterBody()` method is instance of the `BodyContext` and you can use all it's methods to access its child nodes of specific type.

**UPD** If your grammar only defines a boolean expression and you use it only for validation and tokenization, you won't need parser at all. Just use lexer to get list of all tokens:

```
input_stream = antlr4.FileStream('input.txt')

# Instantiate an run generated lexer
lexer = BooleanLexer(input_stream)
tokens = antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer)

# Parse all tokens until EOF
tokens.fill()

# Print tokens as text (EOF is stripped from the end)
print([token.text for token in tokens.tokens][:-1])
```

Comment: I wrote a parser for boolean expressions using the shunting-yard algorithm, so I simply want to tokenise boolean expressions so I can then feed them into said algorithm. From that I generate an expression tree in the form of a dictionary. Should I just do this with `getChildren` and then recursively call it on every sub-element until I get the expected result?

Comment: In case you have grammar only for boolean expression, see updated answer. If boolean expression grammar is a part of a larger grammar, you need to recursively call `getChildren()` to collect only relevant tokens.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I use a mixed approach, I use ANTLR for everything up to that point and then I parse it manually (just because I find it easier that way). I was hoping to get away from using `getChildren` as I feel like I'll have to keep calling it on every element's sub-elements etc. And I've realised that I want to extract not just tokens but some parser rules too, so I guess the token stream will not work.